# Convergence of sequences in a poset

Tags: analysis

as we know every bounded increasing sequence is convergent in R. What about in poset. Is every bounded and O-increasing sequence convergent in a complete ordered metric space or not. Please give answer.

Comment: What is O-increasing?

Comment: Sir order increasing.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $1,1.4,1.41,1.414,\cdots$ which would converge to $\sqrt2$ in $\Bbb R$ is not convergent in $\Bbb Q$.